# Swiftmailer at 1and1 hosting

Tags: php, smtp, hosting, swiftmailer

I have troubleshooting with sending emails at 1and1 hosting.

I use swift mailer lib message I receive is `stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to mrvnet.kundenserver.de:0 http://mrvnet.kundenserver.de:0 (Connection timed out)`.

Does anyone have similar troubles? Any solution?

PS. At my localhost everything is OK.

Comment: Hi, could you please contact their support team? I believe every provider have their own settings. Good luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fix SMTP after contact with their support team.

SMTP parameters:

```
HOST: mrvnet.kundenserver.de
PORT: 25
AUTH: without auth
```

Answer (score 2):

Contacted support, they asked me do not use encryption (neither ssl nor tls, both not acceptable), so my options are:

```
host: smtp.1and1.com  
port: 25    
login: somemail@somedomain.com    
passwd: somestrongpassword=)
```

as you may mention i use 1and1's mail (same settings for gmail would not work)